# SSRS Drilldown Report - Group in middle not grouping

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, drilldown

I've made a drilldown report with 3 steps.  Speaking genearally, the main one is by name, then date, then a folder, then the details group is essentially the contents of that folder.

Under Row Groups, it's just like so:

Name,
  Date,
     Folder,
        Details

Date is child of Name, Folder is child of Date, Details is child of Folder.

It mostly works:

```
 *Expand Name, you get dates that that person did stuff on
 *(skip down one)
 *Expand Folder, you get the details only in that folder
```

BUT...expand Date, and you get all the stuff done by that NAME...  There are multiple dates that you can expand, but each one displays all the folders for that name, when it should just be the folders on that date.

Comment: And your question is?  Please show the code you've tried, too.

Comment: Just at the end there--it should be grouping the folders by date...so if I expand the date drilldown, then I see folders only done on that date.   That's how any other group I've ever done works, and I don't understand why...the group...is not grouping...  The code behind the report is kinda long (and not sure I'm able to put work stuff up), but it generates a table where the name, date & folder all simply repeat so I can show the details without duplicates in the table.

Comment: Sounds like you've made a mistake in the implementation somewhere, but if you can't show us the implementation code, we really can't even guess where the mistake could be.